# How does React measure DOM Elements in useLayoutEffect hook correctly before browser gets a chance to paint?

Tags: reactjs

In the Official React docs, for [`useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect), it is mentioned:

> The signature is identical to `useEffect`, but it fires synchronously after all DOM mutations. Use this to read layout from the DOM and synchronously re-render. Updates scheduled inside `useLayoutEffect` will be flushed synchronously, before the browser has a chance to paint.

Also, in `useLayoutEffect` we are able to read the updated dimensions before the browser actually repaints.

How does react do that ?

Answer (score 5):

so @Marko is right.

the browser rendering cycle is split into phases, the relevant ones are:

1. style - merge HTML with CSS
2. layout - calculate all elements sizes and positions
3. paint

[Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/How_browsers_work#render)

useLayoutEffect is run after layout but before paint

to achieve that all that you need to do (or what React does) is run the `useLayoutEffect` functions synchronously after adding or changing elements in the DOM tree.

The browser can't run the painting phase unless you release the thread.

What happens is that if you ask the browser for the size of an element it will synchronously run the layout phase to give you an answer.

here is a snippet and a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/layout-phase-5kb9jz?file=/src/index.ts:0-896) demonstrating the idea:

```js
const conatiner = document.getElementById("container");

function busyWait() {
  const array = new Array(100000).fill(Math.random());
  let sum = 0;
  array.forEach((val, index) => {
    const item = array.find((val, i) => i === index);
    sum = sum + item;
  });
  return sum;
}

function addElement() {
  const newElement = document.createElement("p");
  newElement.innerText =
    "this is a paragraph, browser need to measure it to know its size";

  if (conatiner) {
    conatiner.appendChild(newElement);
    console.log(
      "layout phase element size",
      JSON.stringify(newElement.getBoundingClientRect())
    );
    const sum = busyWait();
    console.log(sum);

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(
        "after paint element size",
        JSON.stringify(newElement.getBoundingClientRect())
      );
    }, 10);
  }
}

setTimeout(addElement, 100);
```

```html
<div>
      we are going to test layout / replaint stages
      <div id="container" style="width: 200px;"></div>
</div>
```

- I add a new element
- ask for its size
- log it
- then busy wait (not releasing the thread to the browser)
  => you can see the correct size in the log but you can't see the element on the screen

Comment: Can you add the code here, instead of a link ? The relevant code is not too large, and it would be nice to have this good answer (which is worth referring to in duplicates, IMO) without any external dependencies.

Comment: sure, though the code here is just to let people see it work

Comment: Great, thanks! (e.g. I already linked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75929831 to here)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, it works something like this:

1. You click a button that updates the counter (for example).
2. React updates the counter state.
3. React updates the DOM (browser has not rendered it yet!).
4. Browser renders the change.

The `useLayoutEffect` callback will be fired between steps 3 and 4.

Comment: so how can we read layout (height/width of elements) from the DOM before it's painted? seems to me we need to paint it first before we know the position.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for this is that Browser calculate geometry of the layout and elements and takes into account css AND then goes to paint pixel by pixel on the screen.

Question is how layout hook is able to time running correctly between those steps?

Answer (score 0):

> How does React do that ?

This is described in the *"Here's how this works step by step"* part on the [documentation page](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useLayoutEffect) based on there 'tooltip' example:

> 1. `Tooltip` renders with the initial `tooltipHeight = 0` (so the tooltip may be wrongly positioned).
> 2. React places it in the DOM and runs the code in `useLayoutEffect`.
> 3. Your `useLayoutEffect` [measures the height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) of the tooltip content and triggers an immediate re-render.
> 4. `Tooltip` renders again with the real `tooltipHeight` (so the tooltip is correctly positioned).
> 5. React updates it in the DOM, and the browser finally displays the tooltip.

Comment: yeah but for measuring the height we need to have the element painted on the screen, right?

Answer (score 0):

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75929831/it-is-reliable-to-measure-the-dom-dimention-in-uselayouteffect) and someone kindly point me here where I got the answer. I want to put the answer in a even more clear way for someone who concerned:

Firstly, it is true that the **only way** to measure something in DOM is to honestly add it to some parent, there is no something like "offscreen measurement API" to measure the DOM node without really putting it into the DOM.

When a node is added to the DOM, the dimension is measurable **immediately**, but it **will not visible** until the current tick complete.

```
/** 
 * From @Alissa
*/
const newElement = document.createElement('p');
newElement.innerText =
  'this is a paragraph, browser need to measure it to know its size';

conatiner.appendChild(newElement);

/**
 newElement.getBoundingClientRect() give the corrent measure, 
 even if it is not visible
 */
console.log(
  'layout phase element size',
  JSON.stringify(newElement.getBoundingClientRect())
);
```

Here is steps of how user javascript code platform c++ code run in the single tick(thread)

1. user init some code to change the DOM
2. the platform detect the change and run the layout algorithm synchronously to modify the DOM measures
3. user run some other js code to do something else
4. when there is no js code to run, the platform start to paint the updated frame to the screen

It can be a big source of confusion (at least for me) that measurable and visible have a subtly different timing, and the gap between the two timing is where the `useLayoutEffect` callback invoked.