# It is reliable to measure the DOM dimention in useLayoutEffect?

Tags: html, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

I read the new react doc about [useLayoutEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useLayoutEffect) several times, and it make me rather confusing

Firstly, it say:

> useLayoutEffect that fires **before** the browser repaints the screen

From my understanding, it means all the state before useLayoutEffect complete will not visible to user, it is a actually good point, it can be useful to prevent some undesired "middle state" from being visible, which will introducing a flicking kind of visual experience. Also the code example from the doc seems to demonstrate the point

It also say something similar:

> Call useLayoutEffect perform the layout measurements before the browser repaints the screen

> Before your component is first added to the DOM, React will run your setup function

My question is

**How it possible to measure the dom before the node is really in DOM? if it is in DOM already how it possible to make it invisible?**

I know that react is run in "concurrent mode", "render" and "DOM commit" is not necessarily a one-one relationship, so  some "middle state" rendered by the component do not get a chance to commit to dom. For example, if a state change follow by the `layouteffect`, the result may be discarded if there is a `layouteffect` changing the state again.

However, the **only** reliable way to measure the dimension of a node it to **REALLY** attach it to DOM, DOM is a rather complex environment and there it NO WAY to know it information in "detached mode", if the node attached to DOM, it is sure to visible.

So, how react walk around the DOM limitation and do the magic? Or there is something wrong with my understanding of `layouteffect`

Comment: Good question. I found an answer (after more than one try): [How does React measure DOM Elements in useLayoutEffect hook correctly before browser gets a chance to paint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60769022/how-does-react-measure-dom-elements-in-uselayouteffect-hook-correctly-before-bro).

Comment: @kca, thank you so much, I will never know the answer without your comment. I worked as a frontend for 8 years and believe that when the layout data can be measure, the content **must be** visible. And it turned out to be wrong after I tested several use cases.

Comment: The answer to the question boil down to something like this: The browser will layout out immediately after the dimension if changed by the script, so it is measurable, but the paint will not happen until to current tick complete

Comment: @Guichi as far as I know, the browser won't layout when the dimension is changed, it will layout when it's needed. this is why you should first do all writes to the DOM and then all reads, otherwise you force the browser to run the layout a lot.

Comment: @Alissa Not sure what you mean exactly by "layout". After you change the DOM by javascript API, the updated value triggered by javascript can be measured though javascript API immediately, but such changes will not be visible in browser, so, we got a change to update the DOM again(useEffectlayout) before the last change take effect (the last effect is literally be cancelled).

Comment: @Guichi what I mean by "layout" is the browser reflow rendering phase, when the browser goes over the DOM and calculates dimensions. 
The browser will batch as many changes before running the "layout" phase. Asking the browser for an element dimension will force it to run "layout" immediately. It took me a while, but I found an article explaining the idea - https://www.webperf.tips/tip/layout-thrashing/

Comment: generally, all that I wanted to say was that the browser doesn't immediately run "layout" when a script changes a dimension.